# Update all object values to be rounded by two decimals

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, rounding

I have a dynamic response from an API that could have different responses every time. I need to loop though an array of objects and find values that are type of numbers. Then round them to two decimal places. From the below examples, the object key values could be different each time.

Possible responses from API:

```
response = [
 {
  case: "abc",
  price: "123.1234",
  manager: "joe black",
  duration: "3456.1231321"
 },
 {
  case: "bbb",
  price: "23.4897987",
  manager: "jill smith",
  duration: "78974.12156464"
 }
]

or

response = [
 {
  case: "apl",
  yield: "90.1209312093",
  average: "100.123,
 },
 {
  case: "ltl",
  yield: "80666.23131313",
  average: "4512.7897987,
 }
]
```

Expected result:

```
response = [
 {
  case: "abc",
  price: "123.12",
  manager: "joe black",
  duration: "3456.12"
 },
 {
  case: "bbb",
  price: "23.49",
  manager: "jill smith",
  duration: "78974.12"
 }
]

or

response = [
 {
  case: "apl",
  yield: "90.12",
  average: "100.12,
 },
 {
  case: "ltl",
  yield: "80666.23",
  average: "4512.79,
 }
]
```

Comment: You can use `Object.entries()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you can use Object.entries() to get all of the individual key/value pairs in each item of the array.  You can then loop through these and test for numbers.  Any number found can be rounded to two decimal places and the entry updated on the original array.

Something like:

```js
let response = [
 {
  case: "abc",
  price: "123.1234",
  manager: "joe black",
  duration: "3456.1231321"
 },
 {
  case: "bbb",
  price: "23.4897987",
  manager: "jill smith",
  duration: "78974.12156464"
 },
 {
  case: "apl",
  yield: "90.1209312093",
  average: "100.123"
 },
 {
  case: "ltl",
  yield: "80666.23131313",
  average: "4512.7897987"
 }
]

response.forEach(function(r){
  let rValues = Object.entries(r);
  rValues.forEach(function(e){
    // e[0] is the key and e[1] is the value
    let n = Number(e[1]);
    if (!isNaN(n)) {
      r[e[0]] = n.toFixed(2);
    }
  })
})

console.log(response);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go through all objects of the array with map() and through all keys with Object.keys().forEach. Then parse all values to float if the value string contains a number. Finally round the float with toFixed() which returns a rounded float converted to a string.

```js
let response1 = [{
    case: "abc",
    price: "123.1234",
    manager: "joe black",
    duration: "3456.1231321"
  },
  {
    case: "bbb",
    price: "23.4897987",
    manager: "jill smith",
    duration: "78974.12156464"
  }
]

let response2 = [{
    case: "apl",
    yield: "90.1209312093",
    average: "100.123",
  },
  {
    case: "ltl",
    yield: "80666.23131313",
    average: "4512.7897987"
  }
]

function round(array) {
  let rounded = array;
  rounded.map((el) => {
    Object.keys(el).forEach(function(key) {
      if (!isNaN(parseFloat(el[key]))) {
        el[key] = parseFloat(el[key]);
        el[key] = el[key].toFixed(2);
      }
    });
  })
  console.log(rounded);
}

round(response1);
round(response2);
```